# Show Image from Website URL in Android ImageView

Tags: android, url, android-imageview

To show image in `ImageView` in Android, I am using following code :

```
URL newurl = new URL("" + WebsiteURL + "/images/profileImg/" + objUserData.getImage() + "");
Bitmap mIcon_val = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(newurl.openConnection().getInputStream());
userphoto.setImageBitmap(mIcon_val);
```

It is working fine when I am not assigning `targetSdkVersion` but If I am assigning then It is showing error :

```
02-11 12:07:46.339: E/chromium(25772): external/chromium/net/disk_cache/stat_hub.cc:216: [0211/120746:ERROR:stat_hub.cc(216)] StatHub::Init - App com.Mobile.mytestbuddy isn't supported.
```

Comment: please follow previous question answers.  [this will be helpful to you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471935/how-to-load-an-imageview-by-url-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

I use [UrlImageViewHelper](https://github.com/koush/UrlImageViewHelper) it is super easy to use and works perfectly.